# Prove $D$ is simply connected if and only if any nonzero analytic function on $D$ has an analytic square root on $D$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove that $D$ is simply connected if and only if any nonzero analytic function on $D$ has an analytic square root on $D$.

$\Rightarrow$ Assume $D$ is simply connected. Since $f(z) \neq 0$ on $D$, we can choose an analytic branch for $\log f(z)$ on $D$, then
$$ e^{\frac{\log f(z)}{2}} = \sqrt{f(z)} $$
is an analytic square root of $f(z)$ on $D$.

But I don't know how to prove the other direction. Since there are so many equivalent definition s for the simply connectedness on complex plane, there is no obvious path toward the solution. Can any one give me some help please?

Comment: Why can you choose an analytic branch of $\log f(z)$?  Is that your definition of simply connected domain?

Comment: @user10354138 I think we can prove that a open and path-connected domain $D$ is simply connected if and only if for each $z_0 \in \mathbb{C} \setminus D$, there is an analytic branch of $\log (z-z_0)$ defined on $D$.

Comment: $f(D)$ need not be simply connected even if $D$ is.  So there are something you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $D$ is not simply connected then its complement has a bounded component $K$, and there exists a closed path $\gamma$ in $D$ such that the winding number
$$
I(\gamma, a) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z-a}
$$
is equal to one for all $a \in K$. For those $a$, $f(z) = z-a$ does not have a square root in $D$: Assume that $g(z)^2 = z-a$, then
$$
2 \frac{g'(z)}{g(z)} = \frac{1}{z-a}
$$
and
$$
 I(g\circ \gamma, 0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_\gamma \frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}
 = \frac 12 I(\gamma, a) = \frac 12 \, ,
$$
contradicting the fact that the winding number is always an integer.